# surjectivity of rational points induced by surjective map from affine space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, galois-cohomology

Let $k$ be a local field of char $0$ (which is the case I concern).
Let $V$ be  a variety defined over $k$ and 
let $f: \mathbb A^n\to V$ be a surjective map 
(over the algebraic closure of $k$) defined over $k$.
Is it true that the restriction of $f$ to $k$ rational points
$k^n\to V(k)$ surjective?

After it is answered I realized that I simplified what 
I want to know too much. Please see the comments for the answer 
for more information.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not ! Let $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1$ be defined by $f(x)=x^2$. It is not surjective at the level of $k$-points, because there are elements of $k$ that are not squares.

Comment: Thanks. In fact what I want to know is the following:
Assume in addition that $V$ is a linear algebraic group.
Is it true that the group generated by $f(k^n)$ has finite 
index in $V$?

Comment: Sorry, finite index in $V(k)$.

Comment: @ronggang -- What precisely do you mean by "index"?  Why should the image of f be a subgroup of the group of $k$-points?  For instance, the image on $k$-points of the map $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ is not a subgroup of the additive group.

Comment: I mean the group generated by the set $f(k^n)$ has finite index in 
the group $V(k)$. Here is the main example in my mind. Suppose $V$ is generated by connected unipotent groups defined over $k$. Then we get such a map $f$ according to I Porp. 2.2 of Borel's algebraic groups.
Then the question is whether the group generated by $k$ points of these unipotent groups has finite index in $V(k)$. If $V$ is semisimple then the question is whether the group they generate contains $V^+$ in the sense of 1973 paper of Borel and Tits(
Homomorphismes "Abstraits" de Groupes Algebriques Simples).


Comment: If you're thinking of those specific maps, then it should be surjective. The reason is that the map from $\mathbb A^n$ to a connected unipotent group is not just surjective, it is an isomorphism. The algebraic inverse comes from the formal power series for $\log$. Isomorphisms are surjective on rational points. You might run into additional troubles if the decomposition into unipotents is not canonical, though.

Comment: @ Will: It is not surjective even in this case since in general $V^+$ or $V(k)^+$ is not equal to $V(k)$. e.g. PGL_2.

Comment: For a generically 'etale morphism, and assuming your local field is non-Archimedean, you can just use Hensel's lemma to prove that the image contains a sufficiently small adic neighborhood of the image point wherever it is 'etale.  So the subgroup generated by the image will contain a sufficiently small adic neighborhood of the identity.